# Firebase get user by ID

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to get user information (like email, picture) based on its UID?

I mean not for the currently logged user, but any other user.

Comment: Give your JSON tree, and what have you tried. Also which language are you programming in

Comment: There is currently no method in Firebase Authentication to load a user by a UID. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634039/firebase-android-load-user-by-uid, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-users-if-i-use-the-firebase-simple-username-password, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735377/where-does-firebase-save-its-simple-login-users and probably some more

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is this possible now? loading user by UID in firebase auth? I don't see it in the docs so I think the answer is no

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're using the authentication methods provided by Firebase, then no, you can only get it from the current session/user, and if you need to query for it later then you need to save it in your own datastore.

Usually what I do is load the user data when authentication changes, if it's not there then I save a new object (using the `uid` as key), with whatever data is relevant for the application. If you're interested in the picture then you might need to update your data often.

You can find a more in depth explanation, with some actual samples, in the following question: [Where does firebase save it's simple login users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735377/where-does-firebase-save-its-simple-login-users).