# Vue 3 Firebase Auth get *any* user data by id?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuejs3

New to vue/firebase.  I was able to lookup how to pull up “current user” data from auth no problem but trying to write a js composable that I can pass in any user id (not necessarily current user) and it will return the user object or at least displayName.

All the docs/vids I can find on the topic reference getting info on *current user *only not another user. From the [Google Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users) it says I should be able to do this in the "Retrieve user data" section.  Closest model to Vue code-wise seems to be “Node.Js” but it isn't working.

Here's what I've got in getUserById

```
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'

const getUserById = (u) => { // u = user id
    const userData = null
    getAuth()
        .getUser(u)
        .then((userRecord) => {
            // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
            console.log(`Successfully fetched user data: ${userRecord.toJSON()}`);
            userData = userRecord
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
        });

    return { userData }
}
export default getUserById
```

The error I get is getUser is not a function.  I tried adding getUser to the import but same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to look up information about just any user by their UID in the client-side APIs of Firebase as that would be a security risk. There is an API to [look up a user by their UID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data) in the Admin SDK, but that can only be used on a trusted environment (such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions/Cloud Run), and not in client-side code.

If you need such functionality in your app, you can either wrap the functionality from the Admin SDK in a custom endpoint that you then secure, or have each user write information to a cloud database (such as Realtime Database or Firestore) and read it from there.

Also see:

- [How to get FirebaseUser from a uid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60413628/how-to-get-firebaseuser-from-a-uid)
- [Firebase get user by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39542945/firebase-get-user-by-id)
- [Is there any way to get Firebase Auth User UID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352772/is-there-any-way-to-get-firebase-auth-user-uid)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The use case is something along the lines of a user makes a post then other users can contribute.  Each time someone contributes, their ID is associated in the DB since name could be changed.  I would like to show the names of everyone who contributed.  If I understand, you are saying the only way to do that would be to create a lookup table/document outside of Auth?

Comment: Yes, that's indeed what I explained in my answer and what the links also show. There is no way to look up information about just any user by their UID in the client-side APIs of Firebase as that would be a security risk, so you'll have to take control of that information yourself.